# Create two executables in one Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have some experience with creating makefiles, however I have never needed to create a makefile that crates two executable files. I have done some internet searching and came up with this code:

```
all: main.c sieve.c
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -ansi
OBJ = main.o avg.o max.o min.o sum.o
OBJ2 = sieve.o
ALL_OBJ = $(OBJ:%=%.o)
F = $(all)
stats: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o stats $(OBJ)

sieve: $(OBJ2)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o sieve $(OBJ2)

sieve.o: sieve.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) sieve.c

main.o: avg.h main.c max.h min.h sum.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.c

avg.o: avg.c avg.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) avg.c

max.o: max.c max.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) max.c

min.o: min.c min.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) min.c

sum.o: sum.c sum.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) sum.c

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(F) $(OBJ) $(OBJ2)
```

But when i run the file I obtain this message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I am unsure what the problem in the file would be, any suggestions?

Comment: `all: main.c sieve.c` should be `all: stats sieve` -- assuming `stats` and `sieve` are the executables you want to build.

Comment: @G.M. great! it worked, such a simple fix. All other examples I viewed were very generic